# Angular (6) Change secondary child route without changing parent primary outlet

Tags: angular, router-outlet

In my app I am opening a child of a lazy loaded child view in a named "modal" outlet. The routers are defined as so:

Main app component resolver (here: app is the grandfather route):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppRootComponent,
    resolve: { generalData: AppRootDataResolver },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'backups',
        loadChildren: './routed-components/views/backup-monitor/backup-monitor.module#BackupMonitorModule',
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

Backups component router (here: backups (this route) is the father route, reports is the son route which is displayed in the "modal" named router-outlet):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',
    component: BackupMonitorListViewComponent,
    resolve: { backupMonitorListViewData: BackupMonitorListViewResolver },
    canActivate: [BackupMonitorListViewCanActivateGuard],
    canDeactivate: [BackupMonitorListViewCanDeactivateGuardToken],
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
  },
  { path: 'reports',
    outlet: 'modal',
    component: ReportsListViewComponent,
    resolve: {data: ReportsListViewResolver},
    canActivate: [ReportsListViewCanActivateGuard],
    canDeactivate: [ReportsListViewCanDeactivateGuardToken],
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
  }

];
```

I am linking the son route from the father route using a router-link as so:

```
<button [routerLink]="['/backups', {outlets: {modal:['reports']}}]">Son</button>
```

And, it seems the only right way to open the child view in the "modal" outlet. The problem is, as it is defined, there is no way to change only the "modal" named outlet without re-loading the primary with it, along with the data they resolve...

I have also tried putting the 'reports' son under the main App route, but I have failed to open the child router-outlet that way.

Any clue how to re-route from the father to child outlet without loading the father, or otherwise re-structure the whole thing?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the same issue.

Comment: I believe not. We concluded that it's best just to separate the modal dialog into another component that we can use without name outlets when appropriate.

Comment: I found out about @ViewChild and managed to call the methods on the child component that I wanted to. Thanks for the response.